# Registration form - Checking if data entered ($_SERVER['PHP_SELFf'])

Tags: php

What I want to do is,

1. User comes to registration form.
2. Fills it , press enter, registration goes on.
3. If he doesnt fill it, echo Data Missing.

Where I am stuck,

1. Using isset, it echos Data Missing at the first visit itself which shouldnt happen.

Any suggestions?

I am not looking for any codes as  I want to learn it up myself. Just the idea would do.

Comment: Hint: Empty strings return true for `isset()`

Comment: php script resides top of html. So at the first run, the variable wont be set, and echo Data Missing. A user who just visits the registration form shouldnt be seeing that. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first form load, check the contents of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  // Verify the form has been filled in 
  // If any are missing, display missing data message
  // and display the form again
}
else {
  // Just display the form for the first time
}
```

I also recommend reading up on the [post-redirect-get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), wherein you display the form from a script which does no form processing itself.  The form posts to another handler script (rather than back to itself), which does all the validation and action, and finally redirects to a new location or back to the original form on error or incomplete data.

Read more about the [`$_SERVER` superglobal array](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: Awesome. New to 'Request_Method' :) Thanks Micheal. This should do it just fine.

Comment: @Madmartigan Not seeing any code, my understanding is that it is testing the contents of `$_POST` on the first page load and finding them empty.

Comment: @Michael: Gotcha, this would prevent "validation" errors on first page load (no post). I always just use `count($_POST) > 0`

Comment: @Madmartigan - Yeah, it finds the variables are not set, and gives out the output already. Your code will solve it as I can see, and thanks for adding the link. I was about to google :)

Comment: @Kishor: You will find that `isset()` is going to be true even if the user did not enter a value (the value will be "set" as an empty string). That's what I thought your issue was originally. You'll need more validation than that. `empty()` is not good either as it returns true for string `0`.

Comment: @Madmartigan Will `if ($_POST['name'] !== "")` do that ?

Comment: @Kishor: That's a start, yes it will work (but to avoid notices, use `isset()` too). Maybe something like `if (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) < $your_min_length)`. I'd recommend looking into a form validation class/library or writing up your own simple one, this stuff is very boring and repetitive and you'll use it a lot (and you want to get it right).

Comment: @Kishor You can also check if the value of your submit button is nonempty:  `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` which indicates the form was submitted via that button

Comment: @Michael: ...beware though - buttons won't submit values unless actually clicked (like if the user just presses "Enter" while focused in a text input).

Comment: @Madmartigan  I just love the way you reply. Thanks a ton mate.

Comment: @Madmartigan - Last thing, Can I check whether all the POST variables are not null at once? Just curious, else I will list it out one by one.

Comment: @Kishor: That's why I recommend a dedicated reusable form validation class to help with the monotony. You set some rules, pass them into the class, then validate them all after the form is posted. Hard to explain in a comment.

Comment: @Kishor You can do it with `array_filter($_POST)` and check that the resultant array is not the same size as the input array.

Comment: You mean like `count(array_filter($_POST)) !== count($_POST)`? Never thought of doing that. I guess that's a quick way to simply make sure all the fields were filled in with something, but IRL I don't see much point in it as 99% of the time you still want to validate the fields individually.

Comment: @Madmartigan Yes, that's right- it only works for null (actually false w/o a callback) but complete validation is preferred.

Comment: @Madmartigan - Because am just learning and getting into more, my approach to things would be of low level than yours obviously :D Anyways, my idea with that was validate individually only if all fields are filled. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the "action" code in another page?

That's what I normally due, mostly to prevent the user from resubmitting the data on a page refresh, but it would also resolve your issue.

Comment: I am minimising the no. of files as I always tends to create a new file for everywhere user submits the data. This should cut the it into half, so easier to manage and continue working on the project. :) And putting it in another file solves the problem and I have been using that till now :) Trying out with PHP_SELF this time.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could take into consideration [PHP upload - Why isset($_POST['submit']) is always FALSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337682/php-upload-why-isset-postsubmit-is-always-false) in which they make some valid points about the isset function.